# What is this buffer function doing?

Tags: c

I have some code that has the following function in:

```
//some code before
// buf is a char[] containing shellcode

((void(*)( ))buf)( ); //Not sure how this works
```

Can anyone describe what the above function actually does and how?
Syntactically it is also rather confusing!

The full code executes a *shellcode* and is part of a well known and widely used [Security module](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs/Vulnerability/Buffer_Overflow/Buffer_Overflow.pdf)*, should you wish to view the full source. If it makes any difference `gcc -z execstack` is used during it's compilation.

Thanks.

*(Source on page 3)

Comment: It casts buf to a function pointer and calls the resulting function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is casting `buf` into a function and running it as if it was a function that returns `void` and takes no arguments. Essentially running the shellcode.

From the source code in the article:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char code[] =
"\x31\xc0" /* Line 1: xorl %eax,%eax */
"\x50" /* Line 2: pushl %eax */
"\x68""//sh" /* Line 3: pushl $0x68732f2f */
"\x68""/bin" /* Line 4: pushl $0x6e69622f */
"\x89\xe3" /* Line 5: movl %esp,%ebx */
"\x50" /* Line 6: pushl %eax */
"\x53" /* Line 7: pushl %ebx */
"\x89\xe1" /* Line 8: movl %esp,%ecx */
"\x99" /* Line 9: cdql */
"\xb0\x0b" /* Line 10: movb $0x0b,%al */
"\xcd\x80" /* Line 11: int $0x80 */
;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char buf[sizeof(code)];
   strcpy(buf, code);
   ((void(*)( ))buf)( );
}
```

It copies the contents of `code` into `buf`, laying it out sequentially. The first few lines set up the function prologue(setting up the stack etc). It looks to the machine as if, that the code laid out in `buf` is same it would look if it was actually a function. When casted, the compiler allows you to actually **call** the function starting at `buf`. Pretty amazing isn't it? But it is conceptually simple.

Comment: @EdGeorge when I saw shell-code for the first time in my life - I almost shit my pants! We had no stack-overflow back then to ask about such things.

Comment: Reading and UNDERSTANDING the 21 page document on how that code is produced has currently taken 2 days (and counting...)

Answer (score 1):

That statement casts `buf` to a pointer to a function (with type `void(*)()`), and then calls that function.

```
buf // `buf` decays to a pointer to the first element of `buf`

(void(*)())buf // this pointer has its type changed to `void(*)()`
               // (a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning void)

((void(*)())buf)(); // this function is called
```

Answer (score 0):

`buf` is being cast to a function pointer and then that function is being invoked. `void` is the return type. The last set of parens is where the arg's would go if there were any.